# why the device that create a LAN(local area network) can't send data over it

Tags: android, android-emulator, lan, data-sharing

i have created a LAN using hotspot option of an android device and made other android devices conneted to this LAN. i need to send data from the hotspot device to all other connected devices ?. until now i can send data from one connected device to another, but not to the hotspot device.

i tried to do that using rawDatagramSocket class in flutter. because the app should hybrid.

i don't know if the device that created the LAN have the possibility to send and receive from other connected devices, or it's just impossible?

for the code:

1. the send function:

```dart
   String _data= "test";

    void _sendData() async {
     var DESTINATIONADDRESS = InternetAddress("255.255.255.255");
     RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 9000).then((RawDatagramSocket udpSocket) {
       udpSocket.broadcastEnabled = true;
       udpSocket.listen((e) {
         Datagram? dg = udpSocket.receive();
         if (dg != null) {
         }
       });
       List<int> data = utf8.encode(_data);
       udpSocket.send(data, DESTINATIONADDRESS, 8889);
     });
   }
```

2. the receive function:

```dart
String _data= "";

  void _receiveData() async {
    RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 8889).then((RawDatagramSocket udpSocket) {
      udpSocket.broadcastEnabled = true;
      udpSocket.listen((e) {
        Datagram? dg = udpSocket.receive();
        if (dg != null) {
          String data = utf8.decode(dg.data);
          setState(() {
            _data = "received : $data";
          });
        }
      });
    });

  }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if someone looks for the answer, i was just changed the broadcast address from 255.255.255.255 to the broadcast of my network address (x.y.z.255) in my case 192.168.43.255 and it worked.